# Is it possible to let Chrome display the links in PDF?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, links

I am using Google Chrome as a PDF viewer. One thing I don't like is that Chrome does not display the links. For instance, look at the first paragraph in the following link.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6620

It should look like as follows.

[image]

But in Chrome, there are no green boxes around the links, so it's hard to see whether there are links or not.

[image]

Is there a way to let Chrome display the links properly? Or do I have to use another PDF viewer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not highlight hyperlinks in PDF files; I believe that can be done though in Adobe Reader ([more info here, see the section **Change the appearance of a link**](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/links-attachments-pdfs.html)). To summarize the steps here, choose **Tools > Edit PDF > Link > Add or Edit**, double click the link rectangle, and set your options in the Link Properties dialog box. There are a wide range of customization options, so feel free to explore.

For your other question, I cannot locate any tool on the Google Chrome store which highlights links in PDF files at the moment, but you can easily set PDF files in Chrome to open in Adobe Reader instead. Toggle [this setting](http://chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments?search=pdf) in your Chrome browser (specifically, from Chrome Settings, under **Advanced**, first go to **Privacy and Security**, then **Content Settings**, **PDF Documents**, and toggle on the setting to `Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome`. Then, to set Adobe Reader as your default PDF reader, open the Settings app, go to Control Panel, and select **Default Programs > Set your default programs**, choose Adobe Reader from the list, and finally **Set this program as default**.

P.S. here is a link to [download Adobe Reader for free](https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/acrobat).

Comment: More people would find this answer helpful if you cited and quoted the helpful information from your links.

Comment: Thanks. In the latest version of Chrome, it seems there is no option of using my default PDF reader without downloading the file. It would be great if I can open the file directly.